# Getting "That email address is already registered on another account" when trying to edit my Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I try to edit personal information, such as my location, phone and website, and when I save the details I get the following message:

> That email address is already registered on another account. You can
>   try logging out and logging back in as the other account, or contact
>   careers@stackoverflow.com to merge your two accounts

This is preventing me from making any changes to my personal information.

Comment: Did you try logging out and logging in again?

Comment: @Alex Warren, yes I tried - no luck

Comment: I had a look and found that somehow you had two accounts registered with the same email address. I've now merged them for you so please try again!

Comment: @Alex Warren -Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Alex Warren, I've the same problem too! logging out and logging in again didn't help =/ May you help me with this?

Comment: @FacundoVictor If you have the same problem please email careers@stackoverflow.com with the details